# Estimates of Hessian of Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I am studying the heat equation
\begin{align*}
u_t - \Delta u = f
\end{align*}

where $u \in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega} \times (0,1])$ has compact support on $\Omega$ for all $t > 0$. My objective is to demonstrate that there exists a constant $C$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_\Omega |D^2u|^2 \ dx \leq C \int_\Omega |f|^2 \ dx
\end{align*}

I have come up with the following derivation, but I am unsure of whether it is correct or not, so please correct me if I have (spectacularly) erred.

Using integration by parts one can find that
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega |D^2 u|^2 \ dx &= \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \int_\Omega u_{x_ix_j}u_{x_ix_j} \ dx\\
&=  \int_{\partial \Omega} \sum_{i,j = 1}^n u_{x_j}(u_{x_ix_j}\nu^i - u_{x_ix_i} \nu^j) \ dS + \int_{\Omega} |\Delta u|^2 \ dx\\
&= K_1 + \int_{\Omega} |\Delta u|^2 \ dx
\end{align*}

where $K_1 < \infty$ is equal to the first integral and is finite since $u$ has compact support. Now, after substituting in the heat equation and applying a combination of Cauchy's inequality and Young's inequality, it can be found that
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega |D^2 u|^2 \ dx &= K_1 + \int_\Omega |u_t - f|^2 \ dx\\
&\leq K_1 + \int_\Omega |u_t|^2 + 2|u_t||f| + |f|^2 \ dx\\
&\leq K_1 + C_1\int_\Omega |u_t|^2 + |f|^2 \ dx\\
&\leq K_2 + \int_\Omega |f|^2 \ dx
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_\Omega |D^2 u|^2 \ dxdd &\leq C\int_\Omega |f|^2 \ dx
\end{align*}

since again $u$ has compact support and due to the Archimedean property of the real numbers.

Although cumbersome, I believe the above derivation is sound, but I'm not confident in it.

Comment: If $f=0,$ then you cannot use the Archimedean property.